# c# DataGridView autogenerate columns show only property of base class

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a **base class (person)** and **2 derivated class(person_registered) and derivated class(person_not_registered**
I have a **list of  with inner objects mix of person_registered and person_not_registered **

I have a dataGridView, for show the list, and I have set **dataGridView.Datasource=registry(the list of )**, with the **dataGridView.autogeneratecolumns=true**;

but the dataGridView show me only the columns of the properties of the base class and **NOT show me the properties of classes derivated**

Why??

Comment: What would happen if you made another class that derived from person and added it to the list of persons? Would you expect it to show that class's properties too? What if they were different than another class derived from person?

Comment: what would happen if you were to actually show all relevant code that pertains to your question and or issue..?

Comment: Because you use List of Person(base class) as DataSource.Show the code, difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't show because you have it backwards.

It should be `Person : Registered` not `Registered : Person`

Try these classes:

```
public class Person : Registered
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
}

public class Registered
{
    public DateTime DateOfRegister { set; get; }
}
```

Then fill your dataGridView like this:

```
// Create the Data
List<Person> myData = new List<Person>();
myData.Add(new Person() { ID = 5, FirstName = "Jamie", LastName = "White", DateOfRegister = Convert.ToDateTime("Dec 25, 2015") });
myData.Add(new Person() { ID = 10, FirstName = "Mike", LastName = "Smith", DateOfRegister = Convert.ToDateTime("Jan 5, 2016") });
myData.Add(new Person() { ID = 25, FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Yang", DateOfRegister = Convert.ToDateTime("Feb 28, 2016") });

// Pass the data to the dataGrid
dataGridView1.DataSource = myData;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public **class person**
{String *Name*; String *Surname*;}

Public **class registered:person**
{ datetime *dateOfRegister*;}

public **class registry:list<person>**
{ public new void Add(Person item)
....}
```

In Form Grid:

```
dgvNotRegister.DataSource = this.anagrafica; //list of person<br>
dgvNonRegister.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

dgvNotRegister **show**:
Name Surname
```

but NOT: `show dateOfRegister`

Comment: Really? Class Person contain only `Name` and `Surname` properties. Datasource of your `DataGridView` is `List<Person>`. That is why datagridview not generate `dateOfRegister`. Change datasource to `List<Registered>`